# how to add the dynamically created textbox values using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

please someone help out from this headaround problem of me;

I have dynamically created rows using javascript.Now my task is to add the textbox values.

Since it is dynamically created,all the textbox is having only single id or name or class.

I have one fixed textbox out of this table.When the user enters the value of  the first textbox of firstrow it should enter into that fixed textbox.

Then, if he entered the values in the dynamically created second textbox (all the textbox will have same id's only) then both the textbox values should be added and get displayed in that fixed textbox on key press.

Hope you might understood my problem.

plz help me out.give me some sample codes if possible.moreover my values will be in the format of something like 12:00 ,09:00 ...

first i need the solutions for that same id..how to resolve this id problem so that i can manage..help me

Comment: sorry i cant get your question

Comment: What's the code you use to generate the rows? If it's in a loop, you can append the counter to the id, or maybe generate and store a random number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am getting you correctly you want to dynamically create text-box with different ID, and then want to read the values on server side.

Check out the following code

**If you face any issue(s) in the code let me know.**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DynamicTextboxJavascript.aspx.cs"
  Inherits="DynamicTextboxJavascript" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">

  <script type="text/javascript">
function addElement() {
    var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    var numi = document.getElementById('theValue');
    var num = (document.getElementById('theValue').value -1)+2;
    numi.value = num;
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var divIdName = 'my'+num+'Div';
    newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
    newdiv.innerHTML = '<input type="text"  name="TextBox'+num+'" value="TextBox'+num+'" >';    
    ni.appendChild(newdiv);
  } 


  </script>

  <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
      </asp:GridView>
      <div id="myDiv">
      </div>
      <input type="button" id="btnOfficial" value="Add Another TextBox" onclick="addElement();" />
      <input type="hidden" value="1" id="theValue" runat="server" />
      <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click" Text="Read" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class DynamicTextboxJavascript : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

           ArrayList alForm = new ArrayList();
        //Because my textbox id is started
       // with 2 like(TextBox2,TextBox3.....
        for (int i = 2; i< Request.Form.Count - 2;i++)
        {
            string strId = "TextBox" + i.ToString();
            string strValue = Request.Form[strId].ToString();
            alForm.Add(strValue);
            strValue = "";


     }

  GridView1.DataSource = alForm;
  GridView1.DataBind();


}
}
```

Comment: hi geek this helps me a lot..thank youu so much.I have another clarification too..now if instead of textbox if i want to add one row dynamically how to write the innerhtml code to get the whole row..